# How to navigate from external .cs to .xaml page in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to navigate from .cs to .xaml in windows phone 7.

please tell me how navigate?and how to apss values.

Answer (score 1):

This is well documented on MSDN, including how to pass parameter strings in the navigation URI [(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). To see how it works in practice you would do well to study the code in the Windows Phone template projects that you will find in Visual Studio. Just create a new project using them: they will run in the emulator without the need for you to write additional code.

Comment: Hi,it will work for naviage one .xaml page to another .xaml page.i need to naviage from external class file to .xaml page.

Comment: This question isn't very clear - you don't navigate from a CS file to a XAML page. The navigation is between pages which are displayed on the phone (which are described in XAML and have a xaml.cs code behind file). It sounds like you want to trigger a page navigation from another .cs file than the .xaml.cs code behind, right?

Comment: Is there a solution to this..I wanted to achieve something like this too. @PaulAnnetts yes, you are right, I need to trigger page navigation from another .cs file which does NOT have any .xaml file associated with it

Answer (score 0):

1. you can pass NavigationService (from your xaml)as a parameter to your class(.cs). like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774731/how-can-i-navigate-from-an-external-cs-file-in-silverlight)

   OR
2. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730245/silverlight-how-to-navigate-from-a-user-control-to-a-normal-page?rq=1)